# .split() sequence doesn't work more than one time

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to clear text (to get rid off of all punctuation and spaces) and get it to the same register.

```
with open("moby_01.txt") as infile, open("moby_01_clean_3.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line.lower
        ...
        cleaned_words = line.split("-")
        cleaned_words = "\n".join(cleaned_words)
        cleaned_words = line.strip().split() 
        cleaned_words = "\n".join(cleaned_words)
        outfile.write(cleaned_words)
```

I expect the output of program be list of words as they are in text but by one in line. But it turns out in `for` loop only last three lines itirates and output is list of words with punctuation:

```
Call
me
Ishmael.
Some
years
ago--never
mind
how
long
precisely--having
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found how to solve this problem. Excercise book (The Quick Python Book. Third Edition. Naomi Ceder), Python documenation, and StackOverflow helped me.

```
with open("moby_01.txt") as infile, open("moby_01_clean.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        cleaned_line = line.lower()
        cleaned_line = cleaned_line.translate(str.maketrans("-", " ", ".,?!;:'\"\n"))
        words = cleaned_line.split()
        cleaned_words = "\n".join(words)
        outfile.write(cleaned_words + "\n")
```

I moved `-`sign from keyword argument `z` in `str.maketrns(x[,y[,z]])` to `x`, because else some words with `--` remained concatenated in file. For same reason I added `\n` in `outfile.write(cleaned_words)`

Answer (score 3):

You might want to change this. You are using the `line` again here.

```
cleaned_words = line.strip().split()
```

to

```
cleaned_words = cleaned_words.strip().split()
```